# Como se chama a função de arrastar a janela para os cantos da tela?

Tags: c#, wpf

Como se chama a função de clicar e arrastar a barra de título da janela para os cantos da tela, e elas se auto ajustarem?

Exemplo: quando se arrasta a janela no canto direito da tela, ela ocupa 50% da tela à direita, se for mais acima ou mais abaixo é 25% da tela, o mesmo vale para a esquerda, já se arrastamos para a borda de cima da tela, a janela maximiza, e se ela está maximizada, e arrastamos para o meio da tela, ela sai do modo maximizado.

Essa função é nativa do windows, quando eu criei meu projeto, e tinha a barra de título nativa do windows, essa função funcionava, agora que fiz uma barra de título customizada, perdi essa função, fiz várias pesquisas e até agora não sei como implementar, talvez essa função tenha um nome específico, e para ativar e desativar essa função no windows 10 é em "Configurações" -> "Sistema" -> "Multitarefas" -> no título "Ajustar" -> a função "Organizar janelas automaticamente arrastando-as para os lados ou canto da tela"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha, em procurei, e na gringa isso se chama Windows Snap Feature, em C#, disseram que

```
this.ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.NoResize;
```

ou

```
this.ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.CanResizeWithGrip;
```

resolveria esse "problema" apenas na aplicação.
Dei exemplo em C# por causa da tag. Não sei se vai ajudar, mas pelo menos o nome do recurso tá aí.

Comment: É em c# mesmo, funcionou colocando o segundo código no método construtor da janela.. porém apareceram uns bugs gráficos, em cima da janela, agora tem uma pequena barra branca, mas era isso mesmo, funcionou o que eu queria, valeu mesmo! quando minha reputação chegar a 15 eu te dou um joinha

Comment: que bom que funcionou! :)